# Modernizr Feature Detection not running

Tags: modernizr

Im having problems with Modernizr. According to the beginner tutorials i have read this html should be all there is to it, but nothing happens. What i expect is for the class of the HTML element to change to reflect what features are available and what features are not.

I have made sure the js file path is correct by adding a Alert("Hello"); and make sure it triggers.

What is missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Beautiful Sample Page</title>
    <script src="modernizr.custom.57102.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div >Yo yo yo </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you extract this HTML by using the "view source" option of your browser or by any debug tool (e.g. Firebug or the developer's window of Chrome)?

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking but i wrote the HTML and added what was needed to run modernizr. When it did not work i copied the HTML document from a tutorial. But it was virtually the same anyway.

Comment: You have written some source code in your question. When running this code, the output is fine in my case (the html tag has a lot of classes). So how do you know that it is not working? What browser are you testing with?

Comment: @w4rumy OK! Thanks. Well that is the result i am expecting, but I am not getting it. Thats really weird. How come you are getting it. Do you even have a Modernizr js file called modernizr.custom.57102.js ? Or did you change the filename to one that you have?

Comment: I have a usual `modernizr.js` file, I changed the filename of your example to test it. Once again: How do you know that this is not working? I am sure you check the result somehow. What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry i did not get that. I check the output by VIEW SOURCE on the right click menu. Ive tried in Chrome and FireFox 12.0.

Comment: OK!!! Now i used the browsers developer tool instead and now i can see the changes! It works perfectly then. So i have learned that the VIEW SOURCE of the browsers right click menu is not to be trusted. Strange... THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Great. Well, the difference is that "View source" gives you the **original** source code, while the developer tools show you the **current** state of the page. I will write this in an answer so this question can be solved.

Comment: I have answered the question, could you please accept my answer so that other users see what the problem was? (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example HTML from your question works fine.

Be sure that you check the **current** state of the page using e.g. Google Chromes developer tools or Firebug of Firefox. The "view source" option only gives you the **original** source code, which is exactly the same as you have written before.